# Correct way to set bar width in coreplot?

Tags: ios, core-plot

My bar heights seem to shrink and grow as more data is added to my graph. Is it possible to fix it so that it stays the same (say 10px tall) each time?

Here's what I think is the relevant code:

```
#define kBarHeight 10

-(void)configurePlots {




    CPTBarPlot *countryPlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:19/255.0 green:221/255.0 blue:187/255.0 alpha:1] horizontalBars:YES];

    countryPlot.identifier = @"CountryPlot";

    CPTBarPlot *timeZonePlot = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor colorWithComponentRed:30/255.0 green:33/255.0 blue:36/255.0 alpha:1] horizontalBars:YES];
    timeZonePlot.identifier = @"TimeZonePlot";


    CPTMutableLineStyle *barLineStyle = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc] init];
    barLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor lightGrayColor];
    barLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.5;

    CPTGraph *countryGraph = self.countryGraph.hostedGraph;
    CPTGraph *timeZoneGraph = self.timeZoneGraph.hostedGraph;

    countryPlot.dataSource = self;
    countryPlot.delegate = self;
    countryPlot.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(kBarHeight);
    countryPlot.baseValue = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
    countryPlot.lineStyle = barLineStyle;
    countryPlot.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.25f);
    countryPlot.labelOffset = -10.0;
    [countryGraph addPlot:countryPlot toPlotSpace:countryGraph.defaultPlotSpace];


    timeZonePlot.dataSource = self;
    timeZonePlot.delegate = self;
    timeZonePlot.baseValue = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
    timeZonePlot.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(kBarHeight);
    timeZonePlot.lineStyle = barLineStyle;
    timeZonePlot.labelOffset = -10.0;
    timeZonePlot.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.25f);

    [timeZoneGraph addPlot:timeZonePlot toPlotSpace:timeZoneGraph.defaultPlotSpace];

}

 //Setting the ranges - possibly the incorrect part?
 CPTXYPlotSpace *countryPlotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) countryGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
    CSGeoStat *stat = (CSGeoStat *) self.countryData[self.countryData.count-1];
    countryPlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(stat.count * 1.1)];
    countryPlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-20.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([self.countryData count]*kBarHeight*1.5)];

    CPTXYPlotSpace *timeZonePlotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) timeZoneGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
    stat = (CSGeoStat *) self.timeZoneData[self.timeZoneData.count-1];
    timeZonePlotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(stat.count * 1.1)];
    timeZonePlotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-20.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([self.timeZoneData count]*kBarHeight*1.5)];

-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSNumber *num = @0;
    //Bars are horizontal, too! 
    switch (fieldEnum) {
        case CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip:
            if ([plot.identifier isEqual:@"CountryPlot"]) {
                num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.countryData[index] count]];
            } else {
                num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[self.timeZoneData[index] count]];

            }
            break;

        default:
            num = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(index*(kBarHeight+3)) + kBarHeight/2 ];

            break;
    }
    return num;

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
countryPlot.barWidthsAreInViewCoordinates = YES;
countryPlot.barWidths = 10.0;
```

The first line tells Core Plot to use view coordinates rather than plot coordinates.